# PyDev and settrace breaking silently

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev, multiprocess

I'm trying to debug a Python subprocess (launched with multiprocess). I've created a simpler project with only the following code, launched the remote debugger, and then launched the project. I expect Eclipse to break on the settrace statement.

```
import multiprocessing
import pydevd

def new_proc():
    print("New Procedure.")

    pydevd.settrace()
    print("After settrace.")

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=new_proc)
p.start()
p.join()
```

I see output from the first print statement, but not from the second, and no break is performed.

I then sent settrace() the "suspend" parameter with False.

```
import multiprocessing
import pydevd

def new_proc():
    print("New Procedure.")

    pydevd.settrace(suspend=False)
    print("After settrace.")

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=new_proc)
p.start()
p.join()
```

This time, I see both messages as expected. I then set a breakpoint on the second print statement, and ran again. Now, I no longer see the second message.

Therefore, it looks as if Eclipse is breaking execution when it's supposed to, but not returning control to me. Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

Well, if that's your exact code and you're on Windows, the problem is that you're not setting up the multiprocessing properly (you need to check for the freeze_support())... that is, providing that you're starting the remote debugger properly too: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html

I.e.:

```
import multiprocessing
import pydevd

def new_proc():
    print("New Procedure.")

    pydevd.settrace()
    print("After settrace.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=new_proc)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: What?? Hahahaha. Where the heck is freeze_support() documented to be required for PyDev debugging?

Comment: It didn't make a difference.

Comment: Which OS are you using? (freeze_support is required for multiprocessing on windows)

Comment: I'll check on linux as the code above does work for me on windows... multiprocessing in Linux uses fork(), so, it may have implications there.

Comment: Thanks, Fabio. I'd appreciate you checking on that.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 12.04, multiprocessing.freeze_support() was required for me.